# Check Email Availability After Enter Email address in Mat Input

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, angular-material

Check Email Availability After Enter Email address in Mat Input

***This is my Html Code.***

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <mat-icon matSuffix>email</mat-icon>
  <input matInput etaEmailValidate type="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email Address" formControlName="emailaddress" required (focusout)="checkEmailAvailability($event)">
  <mat-hint align="start">
    <strong>Don't disclose personal info</strong>
  </mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

***Code For TS.file***

```
checkEmailAvailability(email) {
  console.log(email.target.value);

  this.newService.checkEmailAvailability(email.target.value)
    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);

    })
}
```

Please tell me what function I use so I can get called `checkEmailAvailability` method after entering email and click outside

If you need Demo what I am looking  for Then [Click here](https://polls.callicoder.com/signup)

Enter Email Demo@demo.com

Comment: The focusout event you are already using should do what you want. btw: to get the entered email the parameter is $event.target.value

Comment: use subject to listen to input changes for like every 500ms and then call your backed to check if email exists !

Comment: replace focusout with blue and then try

Comment: try using 'onblur' event as it occurs when object loses its focus.
  `<input matInput etaEmailValidate type="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email Address" formControlName="emailaddress" required (blur)="checkEmailAvailability($event)">`